# Javascript Matching Input Value to ID

Tags: javascript, html, input

So I've been trying to assign the value a user inputs to the ID of an element. So basically if the ID is "A" and the user types "A" then the text will turn green otherwise It'll turn red. I'm not quite sure of what the syntax would be and I would greatly appreciate any help.

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/swzzd5bf/2/

```js
function search(ele) {
            if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                if(ele.value.toUpperCase() == "B"){ //this is where I am unsure
                    ele.style.color = "green";
                }
                else{
                    ele.style.color = "red";
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<input id="b" class="box" type="text" onkeydown="search(this)">
```

Comment: This seems to be functioning as expected; the color of the input value correctly changes from default (Black) to either Red or Green; once the user presses enter (onkeydown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the value of element with the ID of element like this

```
if(ele.value.toUpperCase() == ele.id.toUpperCase())
```

[Here is the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swzzd5bf/10/)

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark it as accepted answer. By the way if your IDs are always in lowercase then you should turn the input to lowercase and compare:
if(ele.value.toLowerCase() == ele.id)